# integrate mule with alfresco

Tags: integration, alfresco, mule

Is there any tutorial or an ebook that show how to integrate mule with alfresco thorough an example or case study?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Mule_Alfresco_Integration

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The documented solution should work for both Mule 2.2.1 and Mule 3.1, though in Mule 3.1 the axis transport that it uses is not bundled by default in the distro.

Good new though. With Mule 3, a Mule Cloud Connector is under development right now to provide a native connector for Alfresco in Mule based on the CMIS standard. It will have full syntax support in the Mule config to integrate with Alfresco. It should be available in the MuleForge (http://www.muleforge.org) in a few weeks.